# ZeroDivisionError: as 'integer division or modulo by zero' but get as 'division by zero

Tags: python, exception, divide-by-zero

I want to get the exception of  ZeroDivisionError: as 'integer division or modulo by zero', but I get as 'division by zero'. How can I get that?

```
a=int(input())
b=[]
for i in range(a):
    b.append(list(input().split()))
    try:
        print(int(int(b[i][0])/int(b[i][1])))
    except Exception as e:
        print( "Error Code: ", e)
```

Comment: Why? You aren't doing a modulus operation here. You're doing a division. The message you're getting is perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python exception is `ZeroDivisionError`:

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

If you are trying to handle the exception, do an:

```
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
```

instead of trying to match the exception description.

If this answer doesn't cover you, please expand on what your needs are and why, so that we help you.

PS A naïve way to accomplish what you seem to ask:

```
>>> try: 1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...  raise ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: "//" integer division is worked,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have a reason for wanting the specific error message (maybe to understand `float` vs `int` division) so I'll address that.

Even though there is only one divide by zero exception (`ZeroDivisionError`) it's given with a different error message depending on the types used and the operation involved.

If you're trying to get the integer division exception message (`"integer division or modulo by zero"`), you need to perform integer division specifically using `//` instead of `/`. Converting numbers to integers with `int()` before or after dividing doesn't make `/` perform integer division.

As an example of how the error messages vary depending on the types involved:

```
>>> 5 / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> 5.0 / 0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
>>> 5 // 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> 5.0 // 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float divmod()
```

The above pertains to Python 3. `/` division in Python 2 of two `int` objects where the denominator is zero would result in the `"integer division or modulo by zero"` message.

Comment: Thank, Integer division is worked "//"

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please consider clicking the check mark next to it, so the question can be marked as resolved.